# How can I make templates for custom content available to both the web and unit tests?

Tags: unit-testing, mstest, handlebars.net

We are using Handlebars.net to enable templating in our asp.net web application. We offer user-customizable templates in the database as well as "canned" templates that devs create and make available through the filesystem on the web. In order to be sure our canned templates are rendering properly, I would like to test them with MSTest unit tests.

How can I ensure the same file from the web site is being loaded with MSTest in a separate test project in the same solution?

Comment: Are your canned templates also stored in the database?

Comment: No they are stored as text files

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that loads your HandleBars templates and fills them in with data:

```
var htmlTemplateStr = //Open your "Canned Template" and load it into this string

var LoadedTemplate = Handlebars.Compile(htmlTemplateStr);

var contextObject = //create an object that will hold all the variables your 
                  // template will be looking for

var outputHtml = LoadedTemplate(contextJson);
```

Encapsulate this code into its own project. Have this project be referenced by both the project that has your web code, and the project that has your tests, to generate the handle bars HTML. Now you're guaranteed that the same template files are being used by your web code and your test suite. For more details, see the this answer's comments below.

***Update 09/06***

In your third project, you can add your "canned template" HTML files as a [project resource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fc1e5by.aspx). Check out the link for details. My team set its "Build Action" as "Embedded Resource" (so it is embedded into the compiled dll), and set its "Copy To Output Directory" to "Do not Copy" (there shouldn't be anything to copy, since it will be embedded into the dll.)

Once the canned template HTML file is added to your project as a resource, you can retrieve the HTML with the following function:

```
private string GetCannedTemplateHtml(string resourceFilename)
{
    Assembly assem = this.GetType().Assembly;
    using(Stream stream = assem.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceFilename))
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand handlebars. I want to use the same file in the web project and also the test project

Comment: Right. What I'm saying is you should restructure your code such that the Handlebars stuff is in a third project. And the template files, which you want to be the same for the web and test projects, should also live in that third project. Your web and test-suite projects should each reference that third project.

Comment: So when your web code needs to generate handlebars HTML, it'll make a call into that third project to handle that. When your unit test suite needs generate handlebars HTML, it'll also make the same call into that third project. This guarantees both your web and test projects will be using the same template files, since it lives in that third project they're both referencing and using.

Comment: Yes, but *how*? I've seen test settings solutions, I've tried using linked files, the only thing I could get to work reliably was copying the files in both places. I'm looking for the MSBuild mechanics of getting a file from one project to be visible to a different MSTest project...

Comment: When I say both projects are guaranteed to use the same file, I don't mean they'll directly make use of the "canned template file". They shouldn't be. They're "using the same file" in the sense that they are both making the same API call into the third project, which uses your canned template file to generate and return the outputHtml. Lemme know you'd like me to clarify further.

Comment: If my third project compiles to a .dll, how do I tell that project to bring over these .html files with it, so that MSTest can reliably find them and parse them? I don't agree that html files should be stored and maintained in a .dll, but saying I did, how would that physically work? What settings do I have to apply in Visual Studio to get that result?

Comment: Also, my html files will be contained in a .dll project, but will somehow be published to the web? Now I've got two problems instead of just one.

Comment: Regarding how to store your HTML in the third project: I just updated my answer with instructions on how to add your canned template html files as Project Resources that get embedded into the dll, (so they go wherever the dll goes).

Comment: Regarding how your HTML gets published to the web, it should be pretty straight forward. The controller will call the method in the third project to generate the HTML, and that method will return a string, or byte array, or whatever format you prefer. That value will be stored in a System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage object's Content property, and your controller will return that HttpResponseMessage object. I can update the answer with a code sample of this if you need it, let me know!